Difference between quotient group and quotient topology
Suppose $(X,\tau_X), (Y,\tau_Y),(Z,\tau_Z)$ are topology space, let $p: X\to Y$ is a surjective map, we have if $g: Y\to Z$ is continuous $\iff f:=g\circ p$ is continuous, then $\tau_Y$ is quotient topology induced by $p$, see this. Since quotient structure of group is similar to quotient structure of topology space in sense, I guess the following statement is true: Suppose $G,K,H$ are groups, and $\pi: G\to K$ is surjective map(not must be a homomorphism correspond to $p: X\to Y$ not must be a continuous map), if $\Phi:K\to H$ is a group homomorphism $\iff \phi:= \Phi \circ \pi$ is a group homomorphism, then $K\cong G/N$(N is a normal subgroup of $G$).
Here are my attempt: at first we should determine what is $N$, since we get topology structure from $p$, so I guess we can get $N$ from $\pi$, then I consider $ker(\pi)$, but $\pi$ is not a homomorphism, it can not be a normal subgroup in general, so I guess $N=ker(\phi)$. Define $\Phi':K\to G/ker(\phi)$ ($k\mapsto k_{\pi}ker(\phi)(k_{\pi}\in\pi^{-1}(k)$). I proved that $\Phi'$ is well-defined and epimorphism, but I can't prove it is injective, because it is equivalent to $\Phi$ is injective.
So the statement of quotient group doesn't holds like quotient topology space, maybe it holds for some $N$, but I can't find other normal subgroup.
Here are my questions:

Can we find a normal subgroup from just a surjective map $\pi$ just like we can always give $Y$ a topology structure from a surjective map $X\to Y$.

Quotient group and quotient topology have similar statement about＂universal property＂, but what happened  similar statement above holds on topology but not holds on group? Thanks for your attention!



Please ask one question at a time

@Shaun I'm sorry, but I think these two question are relevant, I just subdivision a question.

I got confused here: "not must be a homomorphism correspond to p:X→Y not must be a continuous map". Can you please rewrite this using positive language, that is without using negations if possible.

@RandyMarsh It means we consider $G$ and $K$ just a set, $\pi$ is just a map from a set $G$ to set $K$. Since when we consider $p: X\to Y$, we just consider $Y$ is a set, not any structure on it.

You cannot get the result if $H$ is fixed. While $G$ and $K$ are fixed, the statement must be made for all groups $H$ and all maps $K\to H$.
Note that the same is true in the toplogical space setting. You have slightly misstated the property. As you can see in the link you give, it says "for any topological space $Z$..." (emphasis added), whereas your phrasing has $Z$ a fixed topological space.
The result is false in toplogy too if you fix $Z$: just take $Z$ to be the one element topological space. Then the biconditional holds because the only maps are always continuous, but the map $p$ need not be a quotient map. Or take an arbitrary topological space but give it the indiscrete topology so again all maps are always continuous.
The correct statement for topological spaces is:

Suppose $(X,\tau_X), (Y,\tau_Y)$ are topology space, let $p: X\to Y$ is a surjective map. If we have that if for every topological space $(Z,\tau_Z)$, $g: Y\to Z$ is continuous $\iff f:=g\circ p$ is continuous, then $\tau_Y$ is quotient topology induced by $p$.

(Note the italics)
So I think this is the corresponding statement that you want to prove:

Theorem. Let $G$ and $K$ be groups, and let $\pi\colon G\to K$ be a surjective set function (not necessarily a group homomorphism). Suppose that

For every group $H$ and every set map $\Phi\colon K\to H$, $$\begin{align*}
\Phi&\text{ is a group homomorphism} \\
&\iff \Phi\circ \pi\text{ is a group homomorphism.}\end{align*}$$

Then there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $K\cong G/N$.

In fact, we can make this even more precise:

Theorem. Let $G$ and $K$ be group, and let $\pi\colon G\to K$ be a surjective set function (not necessarilly a group homomorphism). Then the following are equivalent:

For every group $H$ and every set function $\Phi\colon K\to H$,
$$\begin{align*}\Phi&\text{ is a group homomorphism}\\
&\iff \Phi\circ\pi\text{ is a group homomorphism.}\end{align*}$$

There is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $G/N\cong K$.



This implies the first theorem; note that just an abstract isomorphism between $K$ and $G/N$ need not yield condition $1$: just take $K=G/N$ but let $\pi$ be a set function that does not send $e$ to $eN$.
To prove this: suppose first that $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $G/N\cong K$; that is, $N=\ker\pi$ and $\pi$ is a group homomorphism. Then clearly for any group homomorphism $\Phi\colon K\to H$ we have $\Phi\circ\pi$ is a composition of homomorphisms, hence a group homomorphism. Conversely, if $\Phi\circ\pi$ is a group homomorphism, then given $x,y\in K$, we want to show that $\Phi(xy)=\Phi(x)\Phi(y)$. Let $a,b\in G$ be such that $\pi(a)=x$ and $\pi(y)=b$ (we are assuming $\pi$ is surjective). Then
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi(xy) &= \Phi(\pi(a)\pi(b))\\
 &= \Phi(\pi(ab))&\text{$\pi$ is a homomorphism}\\
 &= \Phi(\pi(a))\Phi(\pi(b)) &\Phi\circ\pi\text{ is a homomorphism}\\
&= \Phi(x)\Phi(y),
\end{align*}$$
as desired. This proves 1.
Conversely, assume that 1 holds. Taking $H=K$ and $\Phi=\mathrm{id}_K$ we conclude that $\mathrm{id}_K\circ \pi = \pi$ is a group homomorphism. Then by the First Isomorphism Theorem we know that if $G$ is a group and $f\colon G\to M$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then $f$ induces an isomorphism $G/\ker(f)\to M$, so $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $\overline{\pi}\colon G/\ker(\pi)\to K$. Setting $N=\ker(\pi)$ yields 2. $\Box$
As to question 2, as stated the result also does not hold in topology (until fixed).
Here's a related question, though. Given a topological space $X$ and a surjective map $p\colon X\to Y$ to a set $Y$, we can always give $Y$ a topology that will make $p$ the quotient map. How about groups? Given a group $G$ and a set $Y$, and surjective set map $\pi\colon G\to Y$, does there always exist a group structure on $Y$ such that $\pi$ is a group homomorphism? The answer is "no", because in a surjective group homomorphism all fibers must have the same cardinality (that is, if $f\colon G\to K$ is a homomorphism, then for all $k_1,k_2\in K$ we have that $|\{g\in G\mid f(g)=k_1\}| = |\{g\in G\mid f(g)=k_2\}|$). So all you need is a surjective map where fibers don't all have the same size to get a surjective map that cannot be turned into a group homomorphism.
Why does this happen with groups and not with topological spaces? I suspect that the "categorical" answer is the same answer as to why in topology the underlying set of a coproduct is the coproduct of the underlying sets, but not for groups: that for topological spaces, we have both a left and a right adjoint to the underlying set functor, but for groups the underlying set functor only has a left adjoint, not a right adjoint. So there is always a way to go from groups and group homomorphisms to their underlying sets and those set maps between them, but there isn't always a way to go from sets and set maps to groups that have those sets as underlying sets and those maps as group homomorphisms. By contrast, with topological spaces, you can, using the other adjoint functor.

Thanks for your great answer and patience！In fact, I didn't fix topology space $Z$, but I do fix group $H$ without even realizing it.  I don't understand the essential reason by using category theory, I don't study that yet. I think I will understand what are you saying in the last paragraph. Thank you again very much！
